# pecl oauth package installed but not reflected in phpinfo

Tags: oauth, pear, pecl, php

I have installed the php oauth 1.2.2 consumer extension aside PHP 5.3.3 on Ubuntu:

```
~$ pecl list

Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package Version State
mongo   1.1.4   stable
oauth   1.2.2   stable
```

However it's not showing up in the output of phpinfo() nor can I use it:

```
Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found in ...
```

I haven't run into the same problems with other packages installed through pecl (i.e. mongodb). My include_path is .:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear

Is there another way I can verify that the package is indeed installed and available to php?

Comment: Do you have a line like `extension=oauth.so` in your php.ini to load the extension? You probably have to restart apache too if you're using mod_php.

Comment: Sure enough, I didn't... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Check you've enabled the pecl extension in `/etc/php.ini`

`extension=oauth.so`